What’s the reasoning behind Luke saying “I guess you’re too small to run away on me if I take this off”?
In Star Wars: A New Hope, Luke Skywalker takes off R2-D2’s restraining bolt with the rationale:

Oh, yeah, well, I guess you're too small to run away on me if I take this off!

The statement seems not to make sense - why would a droid’s small size prevent it from leaving? Did the writers have a rational idea behind Luke’s statement?

Some larger droids have longer legs and/or bigger motors, so they could move faster. R2-D2 does in fact appear to be pretty slow over land, so Luke was probably right.

No supporting evidence, but droids require power. Think of when Luke has to plug Artoo in on Dagobah. He perhaps was referring to that given the remoteness of the farm, there wasn't anywhere significant Artoo could venture to.

Suspect there's also an aspect of "you're small enough that I can snatch you up and not worry that you'll drag me off and/or bull through me".

Q. What's R2D2 short for? A. Because he's got little legs.

Not sure you can ascribe too much meaning to George Lucas' throwaway line meant to rationalize R2's escape. It wasn't established in the original movie what how the restraining bolts were supposed to restrain, anyway, other than giving Luke a way to zap C-3PO.

Despite having 'legs', R2D2 used wheels/treads, primarily (ignoring the thrusters from the prequels... there's justification for why), so, in the desert, he's not going to be that hard to chase.  C3P0, with Human style legs, could run in the desert -- R2, not so much.  Were he Huge (think like the Jawa crawler), that would be another issue.. but his size (coupled with his method of locomotion) makes him a minimal 'flight risk' in the desert.
